# ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Angular template with monorepo

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

The template's default structure has everything in one place, like this:

```
/
  bin/
  obj/
  ClientApp/
  myproject.csproj
  Startup.cs
  etc.
```

My structure has many libraries and angular apps - i.e. a monorepo - so it must be more organized:

```
/
  libs
    client
    client2
    server
      bin/
      obj/
      myproject.csproj
      Startup.cs
    lib1
    lib2
```

I edited various references to reflect this structure, most importantly `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
  configuration.RootPath = "../../../../client/dist";
});

// and

app.UseSpa(spa => {
  spa.Options.SourcePath = "../../../../client";
});
```

But when running I get: `InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'npm'`.

When I run the server and client separately, they work... so the problem is with how the "spa services" is configured. I tried both `../../../../client` (from bin directory) and `../client` (from server project's base directory).

How do I reconfigure the project structure? (Is there a working sample repo somewhere?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run your app in dist folder when you are in development mode because dist folder only use for production mode

Default settings is like this

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
   configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
   spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
      spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
   }
});
```

So in order to run your app you must create folder in same root of default Startup.cs or ClientApp file like in your case is libs then it will be libs/client

Then modify the setting

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
       configuration.RootPath = "libs/client/dist";
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
       spa.Options.SourcePath = "libs/client";

       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
          spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
       }
    });
```

Please note that you can only run 1 angular app with this setting if you want to run another angular app you need to manage it selft manually

Comment: Thanks, but this assumes the server and client are at the same level in the hierarchy, which is not what I want. I want complete separation between them.

Comment: How do you want seperate ? Run you angular app in diferren port or same port as your ASP.Net Core app ?

Comment: Separate like I show in the question. Nothing to do with ports. Just change directory structure. The template is a mess if you are using a monorepo.

Comment: Please see my second code snippet. I put it in libs/client folder like want and I already mention ```Please note that you can only run 1 angular app with this setting if you want to run another angular app you need to manage it selft manually```

Comment: No that isn't the way like I already said above - the paths imply that the `Startup.cs` is outside its own project, and is within the parent root of the client project - i.e. the server is the parent of the client. In a monorepo every project is separate, but there are links between them for building, etc. Thanks for trying... :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

1 changed to monorepo structure as shown in my question above

2 edited `Server.csproj` (paths are relative to server app's directory):

```
<!--<SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>-->
<SpaRoot>../client/</SpaRoot>
```

3 edited `Startup.cs` (paths are relative to workspace's directory):

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
  //configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
  configuration.RootPath = "./libs/client/dist";
});
```

and

```
app.UseSpa(spa => {
  //spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
  spa.Options.SourcePath = "./libs/client";
  // etc.
});
```